# Может ли за доменом выcшего уровня сразу следовать домен третьего уровня?

Tags: dns, домен

Согласно [этой ссылке](http://www.uni-koeln.de/%7Epbogusze/posts/TLD_for_localhost_services.html), localhost является доменов высшего уровния (TLD).

Возникает вопрос - может ли за TLD сразу следовать домен третьего уровня и так далее?
Возникает он тогда, когда мы переключаемся из режима локальной разработки на продакшен, при этом
нам нужно в режиме локальной разработки протестировать зависящую от поддоменов логику.

Допустим, у нас есть поддомены локали **ru** и **en**. Тогда в режиме локальной работки у нас будут
домены **localhost**, **ru.localhost** и **en.localhost**. На продакшене же у нас будет полноценный домен,
состояющий как минимум из двух уровней (к примеру, **example.com**). Тогда помимо **example.com** у нас будут
**ru.example.com** и **en.example.com**.

Таким образом, при переключении в режим продакшена у нас произойдёт либо смещение на один уровень,
либо просто в **ru.localhost** просто пропущен SLD. Что из этого?

Ну и ещё, бывают ли другие подобные случаи, аналогично localhost?

Comment: Что-то я не очень въехал в суть вопроса. Уровни это всего лишь нумерация частей домена справа налево. Никто не запрещает сделать любой домен с любыми уровнями, например https://ru.forex/ (там ошибка 403, но всё-таки открывается)

Comment: Ну и даже без экзотики никто не запрещает разместить разные языки на разных доменах например `ru-example.com` - `en-example.com` или `example.com` - `example.ru`, так что рассуждать про уровни я в принципе не вижу никакого смысла

Comment: *Ну и ещё, бывают ли другие подобные случаи, аналогично localhost?* — да сколько угодно. открываете словарь на случайной странице, отсчитываете четырнадцатое слово сверху — вот вам и домен высшего уровня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отчет доменов идет по порядку справа налево, поэтому за доменом первого уровня всегда следует домен второго уровня. Пропуски в номерах не предусмотрены, написать можете все, что угодно между точками.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за комментарий. Я правильно Вас понял, что переключении с **localhost** на **example.com** все поддомены наподобие **ru** в **ru.localhost** смещаются со второго уровня на третий?

Comment: @БоковГлеб, да, все правильно. Это просто нумерация по порядку без пропусков, ничего особенного или сложного. При переключении у вас соответственно `com` - первый уровень, `example` - второй, и `ru` - третий в домене ru.example.com.

Comment: Хорошо. я зачёл Ваш замечательный ответ и проголосовал за него. Спасибо большое!